# Apps Script to copy a Sheets range, move the value down a row and enter a new value in the original range

Tags: google-apps-script

The Code:

```
function UpTrendDetection_1h() {

  var currentHigh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!M2").getValue()
  var currentHH = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!B16").getValue()
  var highDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!L2").getValue()
  var lowDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!N2").getValue()

// IF M2 > B16 AND L2 > N2
  if ((currentHigh > currentHH) && (highDate > lowDate))

  // Copy previous contents of P2:S2 down one row to P3:S3 shift any other cells with values down a row
    var newTrendData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!L2:O2").getValues()
    for (var row = 0, numRows = newTrendData.length; row < numRows; row++) {
    var rowContainsData = newTrendData[row].some(function isNonBlanky_(element, index, array) {
    
      return element !== null && element !== undefined && element !== '';
    });
    if (rowContainsData) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().appendRow(newTrendData[row]);
      
    }
  }
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!P2:S2").clearContent();

  // Print values of L2:O2 in P2:S2
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!P2:S2").setValues(newTrendData)
  {
     
  }

  
}
```

The Problem:

The range copies when the M2 > B16 and L2 > N2 condition is met but the cells do now copy downward in the P2:S2 range to create a history/logging effect of the range.

Example Sheet:

[image: minimal example of sheet]

Comment: It is quite hard to fully visualize & understand your goal here. It would be better if you could _share a sample sheet with sample data_ so the community will be able to **replicate your code**. Additionally, when you say that **"copy the current values in range P2:S2 to P3:S3 and any other rows should shift down by 1 as well"**, I think it would also mean that the value of **B16** would also move from the 16th row to 17th, so on and so forth, thus this could break the line in your code for `var currentHH = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!B16").getValue()`.

Comment: I want to write the values to blank cells in the rows below in a copy/paste kind of way. not create new rows for the reason you stated. The sheet has thousands of rows this range is blank in all of them. I will do my best to produce a sample sheet to work with

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 post updated with example sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

In my understanding, here are your goals:

1. If `M2 > B16 AND L2 > N2` are `true`, get the value of range `L2:O2`.
2. Make sure the `L2:O2` values are not empty.
3. Copy the value of `L2:O2` and place it on the `P2:S2` range.
4. If the `P2:S2` range already has an existing value, it will be moved to the next row, making sure new values on the `L2:O2` range are always added at the top.

I have tweaked your script using an array method called [unshift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp), here is an overview:

1. Get the current values of the `P2:S` range (all values including the empty cells).
2. Clean the array values of the `P2:S` range to remove empty cells using the `filter()` method.
3. Add the current value of the `L2:O2` range at the beginning of the array values of the `P2:S` range using the `unshift()` method.
4. Set the new values of the `P2:S` range on the sheet with the manipulated array values of the `P2:S` range.

### Tweaked Script

```
function UpTrendDetection_1h() {

  var currentHigh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!M2").getValue()
  var currentHH = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!B16").getValue()
  var highDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!L2").getValue()
  var lowDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!N2").getValue()

  // IF M2 > B16 AND L2 > N2
  if ((currentHigh > currentHH) && (highDate > lowDate)) {
    var newTrendData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("1h!L2:O2").getValues();
    var rowContainsData = newTrendData.flat(1).map(element => {
      return element.toString().length != 0;//make sure every array values isn't empty
    })
    if ([...new Set([...rowContainsData])].length == 1) { 
      var currentValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('1h!P2:S').getValues().filter(value => { return value.join('').length != 0 }); //used filter to clear blank cells
      currentValues.unshift(newTrendData.flat(1)) //Adds data from 'L2:O2' range into the first index so it will be new value of the range 'P2:S2' once added on back the sheet (the previous value will be moved to the next row).
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('P2:S' + (currentValues.length + 1)).setValues(currentValues);
    }
  }
}
```

### Demo

> After running the script:

[image]

Comment: @Welchums hope this helps. If there's anything that has been misunderstood, feel free to respond.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I appreciate the help. I was struggling to explain the process but you deciphered my words well. I'm still learning how to work with arrays and had not see unshift used before in any of the examples I had come across. I do have a question. Is there a way to accomplish this with for or forEach by finding the last row in the range with a value then loop from bottom up versus top down? This was something my brain was spinning on prior to seeing your response.

Comment: I think it can be achieved using `for` or `forEach` loop, however it would most likely slow down your script _(e.g. you have hundreds of rows to be processed)_ as you'll loop though these rows one-by-one then do an API call _(using methods such as `appendRow`/`clearContents`/`setValues`)_. The advantage of manipulating an array is you'll save time by manipulating the data once within your script then use the `setValues` method to place the manipulated array on the sheet range all in one run.  [See](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).